# python: Using a loop

Tags: python, loops, math

I want to let the user enter a new answer until it is correct, but when I added the break function the code doesn't work.

```
import random

title = "A Math Quiz"
print(title)
    
num1= random.randint(0, 7) 
num2= random.randint(0, 7)


print (f"what is {num1} * {num2} = ", end ="")
while True:
    answer = eval(input (""))

if (num1 * num2) == answer :
    print ("correct!")        
    break 
print ("wrong, try again!")
```

Comment: The indentation is incorrect, you can't use `break` outside of a loop.

Comment: I see, how should it be used? new to coding so i dont know much unfortunately

Comment: The break keyword must be used inside the while-loop.

Comment: Everything starting from the `if` line needs to be indented 4 spaces.

Comment: Just small note, calling `eval` on user input might be dangerous, because the user might input a python code that would destroy your machine.

Anyway, I don't see why the` eval` is needed here…

Answer (score 0):

You're if condition

```
    if (num1 * num2) == answer :
    print ("correct!")        
    break
```

not inside the loop. fix it and need to use else condition after the if condition as I think.

Fixed code

```
import random

title = "A Math Quiz"
print(title)
    
num1= random.randint(0, 7) 
num2= random.randint(0, 7)


print (f"what is {num1} * {num2} = ", end ="")
while True:
    answer = eval(input (""))

    if (num1 * num2) == answer :
        print ("correct!")        
        break
    else:
        print ("wrong, try again!")
```

Comment: yes the code works perfectly thank you very much!